# Rickshaw Secondary Y Axis (using rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rickshaw

I am attempting (with Rickshaw) to create something similar to http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/scaled.html with my own dataset. I only slightly altered the code to match my dataset but for some reason I am encountering problems.

- I have two line graphs, both of which are on different y Axis scales (one set of y values is always between 0 and 1, the other one can vary between one and 3k, so I wanted to use a secondary axis).
- The picture does not show the secondary Y axis, even though judging from the look of both lines being plotted the secondary axis is being implemented.

[image: Rickshaw graph]

here is my code (Note: `element: document.getElementById('axis0')` by the pre-defined css messed up the current formatting I had, so I commented that line out. Both pre and post comment the secondary axis wasnt showing)

```
    var data, max, min, point, random, scales, series, _j, _k, _l, _len, _len1, _len2, _ref;

data = [gon.calories_consumed, gon.percent_towards_goal];



scales = [];

_ref = data[1];
for (_j = 0, _len = _ref.length; _j < _len; _j++) {
  point = _ref[_j];
  point.y *= point.y;
}


// for each series find the max (min) value
// for each element within each ser
for (_k = 0, _len1 = data.length; _k < _len1; _k++) {
  series = data[_k];
  min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
  for (_l = 0, _len2 = series.length; _l < _len2; _l++) {
    point = series[_l];
    min = Math.min(min, point.y);
    max = Math.max(max, point.y);
  }
  if (_k === 0) {
    scales.push(d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]).nice());
  } else {
    scales.push(d3.scale.pow().domain([min, max]).nice());
  }
}


var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
  element: document.getElementById("chart"),
  renderer: 'multi',
  width: 900,
  height: 500,
  dotSize: 5,
  padding:{top:0.01 , right:.01 , bottom:.01 , left:0} ,
  //need to put in x,y pairs
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Calories',
      data: gon.calories_consumed,
      color: 'steelblue',
      renderer: 'line' ,
      scale: scales[0]


    }, {
      name: 'Percent towards goal',
      data: gon.percent_towards_goal,
      color: 'rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.4)',
      renderer: 'line',
      scale: scales[1]
    }
  ]
} );

new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.Scaled({
  //element: document.getElementById('axis0'),
  graph: graph,
  orientation: 'left',
  grid: false,
  scale: scales[0],
  tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT
});

new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.Scaled({
  //element: document.getElementById('axis1'),
  graph: graph,
  grid: false,
  orientation: 'right',
  scale: scales[1],
  tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT
});

new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({
  graph: graph
});


graph.render();


var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
  graph: graph
});
```

Comment: have you figured this out?  having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should create elements axis0 and axis1 in DOM and assign to element property of both Axes
(look into http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/scaled.html example)